# Python - If Statement With input() Not Functioning Inside def() Function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input

Everything in the code runs properly except `def a()` and `def b()` have and if statements that examine and `input` function though when I run the code it will lead to `'good for you'` being printed no matter the input. For instance if I type `False` or `Whatever` into the code which should lead to different results, both lead to the response `'good for you'` as though the input is always `'True'` or `'true'`. I haven't been coding for very long so excuse me if this is an obvious fix.

```
    tsil = ['input',]

while True:
  print('Write A Number (Print "done" When Finished)')
  num = input()
  tsil.append(num)
  print()
  if num == 'done':
    break

if True == True:
  print(tsil)

def a():
  print('you like short lists? (True or False)')
  ans = input()
  if ans == 'True' or 'true':
    return '\ngood for you'
  elif ans == 'False' or 'false':
    return '\nstop making short lists then'
  else:
    return '\nstop printing the wrong things loser'


def b():
  print('you like long lists? (True or False)')
  ans = input()
  if ans == 'True' or 'true':
    return '\ngood for you'
  elif ans == 'False' or 'false':
    return '\nstop making short lists then'
  else:
    return '\nstop printing the wrong things loser'

if len(tsil) < 10:
  print('^ short list large gorge')
  print()
  print(a())
else:
  print('^ big boy list')
  print()
  print(b())
```

Comment: `if ans.lower() == 'true'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your if statement from 
`if ans == 'True' or 'true':` to `if ans == 'True' or ans == 'true':`

See below code:

```
def a():
  print('you like short lists? (True or False)')
  ans = input()
  if ans == 'True' or ans == 'true':   # if ans.lower() == 'true':
    return '\ngood for you'
  elif ans == 'False' or 'false':
    return '\nstop making short lists then'
  else:
    return '\nstop printing the wrong things loser'
```

**Reasoning**

If you check `ans == 'True' or 'true` will always generate `'True'` which is 1st value in `OR` condition.

`bool('any value')` is always `True`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this line carefully
`ans == 'True' or 'true'`

This will always return `True`

You can try

```
print(bool('False' == 'True' or 'true'))
print(bool(-999 == 'True' or 'true'))
print(bool('Unicorn' == 'True' or 'true'))
```

to see its truth-value.

To solve the issue, you can replace `ans == 'True' or 'true'` with

`if ans in ['True', 'true']:`

or

`if ans.lower() == 'true':`

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ans == 'True' or 'true'
```

should be

```
if ans == 'True' or  ans == 'true'
```

and same for other similar cases, since `if 'non-empty string'` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your conditions in the functions are as follows:

```
ans == 'True' or 'true'
```

The python interpreter sees it as being:

```
(ans == 'True') or ('true')
```

and a non empty string is evaluated to true when used in an if statement.

Change it to this:

```
ans == 'True' or ans == 'true'
```